# How to capture screen shot of polymer elements in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I have a web page I want that when I click capture button then it should capture the screen of the web page including google polymer elements and save it in root folder.  I have tried **html2canvas** library but it is not working.

Comment: How do you capture the actual screenshot? Let's start with this.. html2canvas probably doesn't understand ShadowDOM's or Polyfills and therefore doesn't render it.

Comment: Thanks Andy for reply, I found that html2canvas doesn't understand shadowDOM. is there any solution for that. Currently, i am writing my own  function to capture screen shot of my custom component.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use a servers side browser-less application like PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) that is built on the latest webkit. You can also use node to call PhantomJS, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-to-screenshot

I don't think you will get anything working that is implemented on the frontend that is cross-browser compatible.

Or use a service like https://screenshotmachine.com/ that already implements server side webkit rendering engine, e.g. https://screenshotmachine.com/serve.php?img=polymer-tut-appspot-com-FULL-b521fb.png  is a screenshot of the Polymer example https://polymer-tut.appspot.com.

Hope that helps